# Confusion behaviour of nohup

Tags: linux, perl

On running `nohup` with & on command line, it is returning the process id,
while the same command I am running in perl script within backticks and trying to read output is not returning any output.
Can anyone please guide?

```
 nohup rm -rf ragh &
 [1] 10029
```

Comment: I find your question a little confusing. What output are you expecting?

Comment: i need process id of process running in background .. which i initiated using nohup and &

Answer (score 2):

The job number and PID are printed by the shell when starting a background process in a terminal. `nohup` is irrelevant. If you don't start the job from a terminal (i.e. you use backticks in Perl on shell, or you use a plain subshell) the information isn't shown. Why do you need it, anyway? See [perlipc - Perl interprocess communication](http://p3rl.org/perlipc) for details.

Comment: I want to track process which I ran in background .. so i need process id

Answer (score 2):

If you need the process ID of the background job then use the `$!` variable, for example:

```
nohup start_long_running_job &
echo $! > jobid.txt
```

And then if you need to kill the job:

```
kill $(cat jobid.txt)
```

It applies equally with or without `nohup`.

Answer (score 0):

[nohup](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) means that you spawn a new process and execute the script in that context. 
If your command there takes longer than your starting script it will survive the closing of your shell. If you need the output you should pipe it somewhere else

```
nohup rm -rf ragh > log.txt &
```

Answer (score 0):

choroba correctly stated when the PID isn't shown ("*If you don't start the job from a terminal*").
Richard RP correctly stated that `$!` can be used. But for running in a Perl script within backticks, in addition we need to close the command's standard output, otherwise the backtick invocation would return only after the process has finished, because perl waits for the output's EOF.

```
$pid = `nohup rm -rf ragh >&-& echo \$!`
```

gets us `rm`'s PID in `$pid`.